# Cheat Code Scraper

Tags: regex, bash, web-scraping

During breaks, I find myself playing Emerald version a lot and was tired of having to use the school's slow wifi to access the internet. I wrote a scraper to obtain cheat codes and send them to my psp device. I couldn't come up with a better way of removing the extra whitespace. Any areas I could improve on?

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q -O - 'goo.gl/vfYA94' | \
  sed -En '/<strong>([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/,/<\/blockquote>/p' | \
  sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' | \
  egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$|^#'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are mostly after getting rid of `egrep`, so `sed` command to remove empty lines:

```
'/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

Comment: For whatever reason that was the only pattern that removed the empty space gap between the 24th cheat. My first approach was ```sed 's/ //g'``` but I just brute forced with egrep. Thanks for the tip, man!